# Find element position

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have 5 `div` tags with `position: absolute` in a container with `position: relative`.
I want to know the row number of each div.

div position is dynamic and can move to another row by changing left, top, ...!

How can I set 5 rows and display the row number of each div in every moment?

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="top: 20px; left: 30px" id="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box" style="height:100px; top: 90px; left: 530px" id="box2">box2</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 1450px; left: 230px" id="box3">box3</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 550px; left: 630px" id="box4">box4</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 950px; left: 130px" id="box5">box5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean Row 1: box 1,2; Row 2: box 4, Row 3 : box 5, Row 4: box 3? And if they overlap rows?

Comment: even 5 divs can be in one row

Comment: There's nothing like "rowindex" for absolute positioned elements. Maybe you need to keep book of the "rows" in a JS object/array, and update the object/array when you're moving a div to another "row".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

You will need to see if adjacent boxes are within the height of each other if you mean that box 1 and 2 are on the same row.

If not, then the sorted array shows you the top of each box in order

```js
const rows = [...document.querySelectorAll(".container .box")].map(box => ({ id: box.id, top: parseInt(box.getBoundingClientRect()["top"]), bottom: parseInt(box.getBoundingClientRect()["bottom"])})).sort((a,b)=>a.top-b.top)
console.log(rows)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="top: 20px; left: 30px" id="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box" style="height:100px; top: 90px; left: 530px" id="box2">box2</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 1450px; left: 230px" id="box3">box3</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 550px; left: 630px" id="box4">box4</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 950px; left: 130px" id="box5">box5</div>
</div>
```